# CSS Isolation of a folder

Tags: c#, css, blazor

Is it possible to have a CSS file attached to a folder instead of an individual file . So all and only the files in that folder could access it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a shared layout that all the components in the folder use?  And then apply css isolation to the layout?  You'd probably have to use `::deep` a lot, but I think that should work.

Comment: I would love to try it  but am new to Blazor and have no idea where to start ...:(

Answer (score 0):

CSS isolation concept is related to razor components, for instance if component name is MyComponent.razor then CSS file name must be MyComponent.razor.css, it has nothing to do with folder names

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is well aware of all of that, but is curious if Blazor supports the concept of sharing an isolaated css file across more than one component (all the components in a folder).  It's quite possible the answer is no, but your answer doesn't really address this.

Comment: I meant naming convention of files is important for css isolation .

Comment: Is there a way to have access to a css in a folder ...
Do we need to reference it in each file ?
 ie   <link href="Myfolder/Myfolder.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ???